# Edge Animate Automation

Tags: automation, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

Most Adobe products have the ability to be automated using AppleScript or ExtendScript/JavaScript but I don't seem to see the same capabilities in Edge Animate.  Maybe I'm just missing something.  I'm looking to be able to do things like open the document, add images, save the document, etc.  Has anyone been able to find anything like this?  I've done a number of different searches to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I think you're talking about adding your own javascript, which can be done by clicking the curly brackets located next to any of the elements in the animation, or hittin ctrl+E to see the full code.

Second, in terms of opening the document, you should be able to just double click the an file that it creates, and saving the document is just like in any other program, file>save(as).

Adding images is as simple as file>Import (hotkey = ctrl + I).

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what I was asking for, but I did end up finding a solution. I was looking for a mechanism to be able to control Edge Animate similar to how you can control InDesign, Photoshop, and Flash via VBScript, and JavaScript respectively. This allows you to do things like import images into your document from an external script, save the document, export contents, etc. In the end, I wrote some code that sends key-strokes to the application and that resolved the problem although not ideally, IMHO. Thanks for your responses, though.